# How to use a string position in java using array or another technic

Tags: java, arrays

I need to get the position of two different registration number of the different length and i reuse that position i get.

The part i need to target is where **MS** characters stay

I need the way i can tell the system to know if `regNo` contains `MS` and it does something.

```
 regNo : BCS/MS/13/09/0001
 regNo : BCOM/MS/09/0149

 if ( the position 5 and position 6 of regNo equals to S ){
     .. do s.thing 
  }
 or 

 if (the part after / there is MS ){
    ... do something 
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to summarize there are a few options:

- [String#contains](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains-java.lang.CharSequence)  - will show if string contains the specified sequence of char values. The important thing to remember - `contains` ignores position. Both `"MS".contains("MS")` and `"ABS/MS/".contains("MS")` return true. If you need to check that "MS" is at certain position in the string `contains` might not be the best option.
- [String#indexOf](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-) - returns the index within this string of the first occurrence of the specified substring.
- [String#matches](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches-java.lang.String-) - tells whether or not this string matches the given regular expression. It is really useful for verifying the format of the string, especially if position of the substring may vary. In your case "MS" might be at different positions. So we can use something similar to this: `System.out.println("BCS/MS/13/09/0001".matches("[A-Z]+\\/MS.*"));` or more specific `System.out.println("BCOM/MS/09/0149".matches("[A-Z]{3,4}\\/MS(?:\\)"));`  [first regex explanation](https://regex101.com/r/NBSCIC/1)   [second regex](https://regex101.com/r/o4EF2S/1)

Answer (score 0):

use regex

```
 final String msg = "BCS/MS/13/09/0001";
 System.out.println((msg.split("/")[1]));
```

Comment: What will be printed here  ?:  System.out.println((msg.split("/")[1]));

Comment: you will get the string MS

Answer (score 0):

I used  :

```
 String msg = "BCS/MS/13/09/0001";
if (ms.contains("MS"))
  {
   Do . sothing
  }
```

and it worked

Answer (score 0):

```
String str1 = "BCS/MS/13/09/0001";
int pos1= str1.indexOf("MS");
String str2 = "BCOM/MS/09/0149";
int pos2= str2.indexOf("MS");
```

Now you can use values pos1 and pos2 wherever required.

For more specific search you can do like below,

```
String str1 = "BCS/MS/13/09/0001";
int pos1= str1.indexOf("/MS/")+1;
String str2 = "BCOM/MS/09/0149";
int pos2= str2.indexOf("/MS/")+1;
```

Comment: Thanksz@ Anil , what this +1 means ?

Comment: str1.indexOf("/MS/") will give the position of first letter in string "/MS/" ie: "/". But we require the position of "MS" only, so I added 1 in position of "/" in /MS/"

Comment: If your problem is solved, please accept any suitable answer